# zip warning - name not matched

Tags: bash, unix, zip

I am getting the following error while using zip in my bash script

`zip warning: name not matched: test.png test2.png`

```
#!/bin/bash
files_to_zip="test.png test2.png"
zipfile_name=result$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").zip
zip "$zipfile_name"  "$files_to_zip"
```

Note: The images are in the same directory as the script and when i execute `zip test.zip test.png test2.png` , the zip get created just fine.

Comment: If you substitute your vars into command you'll get `zip "result-2017-09-02.zip" "test.png test2.png"` this is different from what you want to achieve

Comment: The name of the zip is an example , i use `test.zip` for simplicity

Comment: I mean your last parameter goes into same "" so is treated as one file name which will not be found

Comment: @Artemy Vysotsky but `$files_to_zip` contain list of files as a string separated by spaces so zip should know they are different filenames

Comment: Why you have not tried `zip test.zip "test.png test2.png"`? If you sure zip has to understand it

Comment: Ahh you are right....zip is treating it as a single filename.What would be the most elegant solution in this situation

Comment: Well use `zip "$zipfile_name"  $files_to_zip` and if you have special chars or spaces inside the names - add quotes inside the files_to_zip variable

Comment: How could i missed that...word splitting is exactly what was needed here.#Lackofsleep .Post it as an answer

Comment: Note that this also shows if you try to zip symlinks that point to non-existing files. In this case add `--symlinks`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When names are combined inside same quotes whole string is treated as file name. Use

```
zip "$zipfile_name" $files_to_zip
```

instead. And if your png names have special characters like spaces - add quotes or escape this characters inside the `$files_to_zip` variable

Answer (score 0):

add this line before sorting the files in directory

```
IFS=$'\n' 
files=($(ls | sort))
```

This worked for me and handled for numbers, dashes, special characters in the input files that are being converting to the zip file